# Cannot display JSON file created and saved in Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

When I create a file in Visual Studio Code (on a Windows 7 box), add some content, then save it, the content is replaced with the following message:

```
The file cannot be displayed in the editor because it is either binary 
or uses an unsupported text encoding.
```

My workaround is to create and save the file in Sublime Text, then I can open it, edit it, and save it in VS Code.

What do I need to do to get the file to save with the proper encoding?

Here are the steps I'm taking:

1. Create a new file in VS Code
2. Set the language of the file to JSON (bottom-right of editor)
3. Enter the following

   ```
   {"menu": {
     "id": "file",
     "value": "File",
     "popup": {
       "menuitem": [
        {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
         {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
         {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
       ]
     }
   }}
   ```
4. Save the file as test.json

Comment: Could you post the code that writes to the file?

Comment: You bet. I edited the question to include the exact steps I'm taking.

Comment: And a final suggestion, also mention somewhere that it is in json, I see visual studio code is not a specific language of it's own

Comment: JSON is just the example. The issue occurs regardless of the language of the snippet in the file. The problem is specific to the feature of VS Code for setting the language of the file.

Comment: Oh OK then, I withdraw my remark

Comment: @user3079666 - it turns out that it is in fact JSON specific. I've added the JSON tag to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in VS Code that has been fixed and will be available in the next update. Sorry for that! It does not happen for all file types, but for JSON unfortunately.

**Update**

Meanwhile new versions have been released that fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in VS Code. If you are running into it, rather than setting the language of the file, save the file with the `.json` extension, and VS Code will detect the language and correctly display the file.

I've submitted the bug here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/issues/detail/16781